# Google Map with two FusionTableLayers not showing properly

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-fusion-tables

I have created two Fusion Tables, one whose rows are LineStrings (Polylines) and one whose rows are Points / Locations.

Then I have an HTML using Google Maps API, loading each Fusion Table as a layer, but when I try to display both layers, the layer I load last doesn't display all the data:

- If I comment out the polyline layer, all markers appear;
- If I comment out the markers layer, all the polylines appear;
- If I load the markers layer first and then the polyline layer, not every polyline appears;
- If I load the polyline layer first and then the markers layer, only the first marker appears.

Even while trying to use the [FusionTablesLayer Wizard](http://fusion-tables-api-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/FusionTablesLayerWizard/src/index.html) the exact same problem happened. There seems not to be any exceeding on service limits, I guess (no so many points in principle)

My page and the Fusion Table links are here:

http://heltonbiker.github.io/audax/AudaxMapFusionTables.html

https://www.google.com/fusiontables/DataSource?docid=1FE-5fUl61ukh_G_qxVrmpRcbkHUOGHWNu6AtpXM

https://www.google.com/fusiontables/data?docid=1atDMX27CGOINRj6UaJpmGbzyaYpFI_WepixrMoA

Comment: Must be a bug.  Your code looks OK, when I copy the tables and use the copies as datasource all features appear.

Comment: @Dr.Molle when you say copy the tables and use them, you mean using them the same way as me, or you use them as "datasources" in any other form? My goal is to have a (shareable) map, so if I can get it without FusionTablesLayer, say, with KmlLayer or in Maps Engine Lite, that would make it, although way less ideally I think...

Comment: I'm using them in the same way, with the code of the linked page from github.io  . I did only change the table-Ids

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/nFg53/

Comment: @Dr.Molle Well, that's weird. I have tried with combinations of almost identical codes, and now the provided link seems to be working fine (with edited javascript). I guess it might have to do with built-in limits combined with styling, who knows...